# Codeigniter: date validation

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

Does anyone know how to validate date. For example, `cannot have 30 Feb`, and `no 31 in certain month` so when the user enter the valid it will be rejected. I was think about a call back function but not sure how it will be done.

Comment: You'll definitely need to use a callback. How you decide to approach the callback will be dependent on your needs and the kind of input you're asking for and expecting to receive. You may consider a callback that implements PHP's DateTime class. Invalid input would return false and the callback would do the same. Or, if you're after a particular format, you could use date_create_from_format(). Again, it depends on your requirements.

Comment: use any jquery date calender plugin to add date in text field it will give you proper date

Comment: Are there any guides on it? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Create a call back function using PHP [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function

Use [this guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) to create callback functions in Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

try this the code also takes leap year into account

```
function valid_date($date)
{    
   $pattern = '/^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/';

    if(preg_match($pattern, $date) )
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_date', 'The %s is not valid it should match this dd/md/yyyy format');
        return false;
    }
}
//and just use this to set rules
$this->form_validation->set_rules('Your date field from html', 'date', 'required|callback_valid_date');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple regex to validate the date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'Date in dd-mm-yyyy',
      'regex_match[(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}]');
```

for validation using `callback` this will make sure of month Feb which is 28 days use this

```
//Add a rule for validation
$this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'Date of Birth', 'callback_valid_date');

//Define a callback and pass the format of date 
public function valid_date($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
   $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
   //Check for valid date in given format
   if($d && $d->format($format) == $date) {
      return true;
   } else {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_date', 
               'The %s date is not valid it should match this ('.$format.') format');
        return false;
   }
}
```